# Is it possible to use Batman.js with cordova?

Tags: cordova, coffeescript, batman.js

I can't get it to work, and I think it is due to

> Unfortunately, due to awesome browser security things, you can't run
>   index.html directly from the directory. You can use literally any
>   server mechanism as long as you're running the app from behind
>   localhost.

in the README, on the example app.

Is there any way to overcome this? Any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not tried it, but I think is possible. There are some "proof-of-concept" repos out there:

- https://github.com/henrydjacob/cordova-batman-template
- https://github.com/ryreitsma/phonegap-batman

Feel free to hop in [#batmanjs](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=batmanjs) on freenode as you're learning!

Comment: Thanks for these repos! But they look like cannons to kill butterflies, with a lot of configuration that I don't need.

I'll search their source to find the magic behind it :)